# php script visible in Dreamweaver but not in browser, any ideas?

Tags: php, dreamweaver

creating my first php site and I'm just making sure I have everything setup. I typed a very simple script:

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

it displays just fine in Dreamweaver's design view but when I open it in Firefox it doesn't display. Any ideas why?

Using xampp, have apache running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What displays when you try to view the file on in FireFox? (blank page? error? etc?) And ensure you are viewing the file by localhost/file_name/... NOT c:\..